# Java Daemons and connecting to already running instances

Tags: java

I'm looking to see if anyone on here has any experience with Java Daemons / Services and connecting to instances of them. Android has a mechanism for handling Services and I was wondering if anyone has used the Apache Commons Daemon code to do something similar on Windows or Unix/Linux.

All I want to do is have an already running daemon and be able to bind to it and once bound, run methods through it.

- Start service if not already running
- Get instance of service & bind to it
- Call methods using the service

Answer (score 1):

Solaris has the Service Manager Facility to run programs as service: http://www.fujitsu.com/global/services/computing/server/sparcenterprise/products/software/solaris10/self-healing/ssm/